# PHP Reference for MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My function:

```
   function sql_query($s, $x) {
        $query = mysql_query($s);
        global $mysql;
        while($mysql = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        return;
        }
    }
```

Now it's work only with **$mysql** variable:

```
echo $mysql['username'];
```

How to make it works only with:

```
sql_query("select * from users where id = '1' limit 1", "varname");
$varname['username'];
```

I want to set a SQL Query and Variable name in function, like:

```
sql_query("sqlquery", "variable");
echo $variable['id'];
```

Thanks for reply!

Comment: Is `$varname = sql_query($query);` too straightforward of a solution?

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated! Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks guys! I use mysqli

Answer (score 0):

```
function sql_query($s, &$x) {
  global $mysql;
  $query = mysql_query($s);
  $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
  foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    $x[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

This *should* assign each variable that is returned by the query to a key in array $x (assuming it is an array). Notice that I am passing $x by reference instead of by value, eliminating the need to return anything.